# Convergence in $L^p(\Omega)$ Norm

Tags: convergence-divergence

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain. Let $u,v,v_n\in L^p(\Omega)$ and suppose that $$\|u+v_n\|_p\rightarrow\|u+v\|_p$$

Is true that $$\|v_n\|_p\rightarrow\|v\|_p$$

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to ask? Convergence *of* norm and convergence *in* norm are different things...

Comment: Yes it is @MihaHabič

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Consider the constant functions $u=-1,v_n=1+(-1)^n,v=0$.